# Qt, can't display child widget

Tags: c++, qt, interface

I have two widgets defined as follows

```
class mainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    mainWindow();
    void readConfig();
private:
    SWindow *config;
    QVector <QString> filePath;
    QVector <QLabel*> alias,procStatus;
    QVector <int> delay;
    QGridLayout *mainLayout;
    QVector<QPushButton*> stopButton,restartButton;
    QVector<QProcess*> proc;
    QSignalMapper *stateSignalMapper, *stopSignalMapper, *restartSignalMapper;
public slots:
    void openSettings();
    void startRunning();
    void statusChange(int);
    void stopProc(int);
    void restartProc(int);
    void renew();
};
class SWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SWindow(QWidget *parent=0);
    void readConfig();
    void addLine(int);
private:
    QVector<QPushButton*> selectButton;
    QVector<QLabel*> filePath;
    QVector<QLineEdit*> alias;
    QSignalMapper *selectSignalMapper;
    QVector<QSpinBox*> delay;
    QGridLayout *mainLayout;
public slots:
    void selectFile(int);
    void saveFile();
    void addLineSlot();
};
```

when i create and display SWindow object from mainWindow like this

```
void mainWindow::openSettings()
{
    config = new SWindow();
    config->show();
}
```

everything is ok, but now i need to access the mainWindow from SWindow, and

```
void mainWindow::openSettings()
{
    config = new SWindow(this);
    config->show();
}
```

doesn't display SWindow. How can i display SWindow?

How do i call a function on widget close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a `QWidget` [isn't a window](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html). If it is not a window and you specify a parent, it will be displayed inside the parent (so in your case it is probably hidden by other widgets inside your `mainWindow`).

Look at [`windowFlags()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) too. Or you could make your `SWindow` inherit from `QDialog`, depending on what you use it for.

As for calling a function on widget close : you could reimplement [`closeEvent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close).

Comment: The problem is why he was trying to do this. He was trying to be able to call `((mainWindow*)parent())->renew()` from inside his `SWindow` class which is horribly bad.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `config = new SWindow(this);` you're setting the parent of `config` to be the instance of `mainWindow`.

This means `config` is no longer a top-level widget, therefore it won't display outside the `mainWindow` instance (specifically, it would need to be the central widget or inside the `mainWindow` instance's layout to be displayed).

**EDIT:** Sorry - I missed your last question; *How do i call a function on widget close*

You will want to override the `QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)` method. This gets called when you close a top-level widget. The most practical thing to do is `emit()` a signal so that another class can handle it having been closed.

Comment: Is there a way to call mainWindow from SWindow without making SWindow a child of mainWindow?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "call mainWindow" - that's your classname. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Call an instance of mainWindow wich created an instance of SWindow. I need to call mainWindow's renew() function when clicking SWindow's button.

Comment: That's what signals and slots are for. You need to define some signals that your SWindow will emit (e.g. `void buttonClicked()`). When you instantiate SWindow inside your mainWindow class, you'll connect the signal from SWindow to a slot in mainWindow - `connect(config, SIGNAL(buttonClicked()), this, SLOT(renew()))`. Inside the function in `SWindow` that handles the button click, you do a `emit buttonClicked()`.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Leiaz, you can use the [windowsFlags](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qt.html#WindowType-enum) flag when you create the widget. It would look like this:

```
void mainWindow::openSettings()
{
    config = new SWindow(this, Qt::window);
    config->show();
}
```

To reimplement the closeEvent:

header:

```
protected:
  virtual void closeEvent ( QCloseEvent * event )
```

cpp:

```
 void sWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
 {
     this->parentWidget()->SomeFunction();
     qWidget::closeEvent(event);
 }
```

However, its probably better to use signal/slots for your case here. Since you said you want to call the parent's renew method on some button click in sWindow, what you want is to EMIT a signal everytime the button is clicked, and connect this signal in the parent with the parent's refresh slot.

```
void sWindow::sWindow()
{
  ...
  connect(ui.button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(btnClicked()));
}
void sWindow::btnClicked()
{
  // whatever else the button is supposed to do
  emit buttonClicked();
}
```

and in your parent class

```
void mainWindow::openSettings()
{
    config = new SWindow(this, Qt::window);
    connect(config, SIGNAL(buttonClicked()), this, SLOT(refresh()));
    config->show();
}
```